# FLUTTER: how ro format Open weather sunrise and sunshine data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to format the json data below to get time only. NOT time and date. But I havent been able to do it. How could you do it?

Thanks for the help.

**Json Data from open weather:**

```
{
"coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 300,
        "main": "Drizzle",
        "description": "light intensity drizzle",
        "icon": "09d"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 280.32,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 81,
    "temp_min": 279.15,
    "temp_max": 281.15
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
    "speed": 4.1,
    "deg": 80
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 90
},
"dt": 1485789600,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5091,
    "message": 0.0103,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1485762037,
    "sunset": 1485794875
},
"id": 2643743,
"name": "London",
"cod": 200
}
```

**This is the part I'd like to format:**

```
"sys": {
"message": 0.0025,
"country": "JP",
"sunrise": 1485726240,
"sunset": 1485763863
}
```

Comment: The JSON example you have posted is not valid JSON since the keys are not Strings. So e.g. `coord` should have been `"coord"`.

Comment: Also, when you are saying you only want the time. What timezone do you mean here? The values in your example are UTC according to the documentation: https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api . But that would end up making to so the sunrise in JP are 21:44 in UTC. Is this what you want?

Comment: I want to convert that data to UTC+3 time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something like this to parse the values for sunrise and sunset and get the hour and minute of each time. Take a look and please tell me if you want any changes:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  const jsonString = '''
{
"coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 300,
        "main": "Drizzle",
        "description": "light intensity drizzle",
        "icon": "09d"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 280.32,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 81,
    "temp_min": 279.15,
    "temp_max": 281.15
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
    "speed": 4.1,
    "deg": 80
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 90
},
"dt": 1485789600,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5091,
    "message": 0.0103,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1485762037,
    "sunset": 1485794875
},
"id": 2643743,
"name": "London",
"cod": 200
}
''';

  dynamic jsonObject = jsonDecode(jsonString);

  dynamic sys = jsonObject['sys'];
  print(sys);
  // {type: 1, id: 5091, message: 0.0103, country: GB, sunrise: 1485762037, sunset: 1485794875}

  sys['sunrise'] = getClockInUtcPlus3Hours(sys['sunrise'] as int);
  sys['sunset'] = getClockInUtcPlus3Hours(sys['sunset'] as int);

  print(sys);
  // {type: 1, id: 5091, message: 0.0103, country: GB, sunrise: 10:37, sunset: 19:55}

  print(json.encode(sys));
  // {"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":"10:37","sunset":"19:55"}

  print('sunrise: ${getClockInUtcPlus3Hours(1485762037)}'); // sunrise: 10:37
  print('sunset: ${getClockInUtcPlus3Hours(1485794875)}'); // sunset: 19:55
}

String getClockInUtcPlus3Hours(int timeSinceEpochInSec) {
  final time = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeSinceEpochInSec * 1000,
          isUtc: true)
      .add(const Duration(hours: 3));
  return '${time.hour}:${time.second}';
}
```

Comment: Thank You, I'll try and implement this into my code and let you know if it works.